# A = B, True or False

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$A = \{2m + 1\mid m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

$$B = \{2n + 3\mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

I've proved set equality such as $A = A \cap B$, by showing $A \subseteq A \cap B$, $A \cap B \subseteq A$ and concluding the equality with laws of set theory. How do I go about this method of proof when equations are involved?

Also, is "$2m + 1$" an element of set $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove equality in sets is to show double inclusion:

$A\subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$

This is a very simple approach then. Suppose we have a $x \in A$. So $x = 2m+1$.   Well then it is true that $x$ is also $2(m-1) + 3$. So $x\in B$. So we have shown  $x$ $\in A \rightarrow x\in B$ or in other words $A\subseteq B$. Now I will leave it to you to finish the proof by showing $B \subseteq A$.

Comment: Using the word "random" in mathematics in this sense can be quite precarious, it seems to indicate some probability at work. "Arbitrary" is safer, most of the time. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
        $$2n+3=2n+2+1=2(n+1)+1$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If you can observe, than both $A$ and $B$ define all odd numbers, there is nothing to do.

Comment: Yes, it is clear that they will both define odd numbers. However, I am studying for discrete mathematics where we must provide logical proofs.

Comment: @ballin But finding a bijection between $A$ and $B$ is acceptable?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: A bijection only proves that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality, not that they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest letting $f$ be a function from $A$ to $B$ that maps an element $a\in A$ of the form $a=2m+1$ to the element $f(a)=a+2$. You can show that this is a injection simply by showing if $f(x)=f(y)$ (i.e. if $x+2 = y+2$), then $x=y$. Also, you can show that this is a surjection by proving $\forall y\in B$, $\exists x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$. Which isn't too bad if you consider the element $x=y-2$ and prove that it is an element of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

As a concrete example:
$$
2m+1= 853 = 2n+3
$$
if $m=426$ and $n=425$.

The question is: given $m$, can you find $n$, and given $n$, can you find $m$?  If so, then whenever there's an $m$ that will serve, there is also an $n$, and vice-versa.  So anything that's a member of either set is a member of the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see where your confusion is. If we let
$$A = \{2m + 1\mid m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

$$B = \{2n + 3\mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\},$$

then we make a couple quick observations:

1. A,B are just sets of numbers; A is the set of all numbers such that the numbers could be expressed in the form of $2m+1$, where $m$ is an integer. Thus, elements would be $1,3,5,7...$ you know, all the odds. Same with B. So to answer your question, $2m+1$ refers to the description of all elements in A.
2. Note that the difference between sets A,B is that the elements of B are simply shifted two spaces over to the right on a number line; plug in integers and you'll see that B is simply $1, 3, 5, 7...$ as well.

To show that the two sets are equal, we have to show that there exists a relationship from one set to the other; if such a relationship exists, then the elements of one set imply the elements of the other, and vice versa. This is why many other responses on this page have instructed you to start in one set, and work your way to another set, and then vice versa.

Here's how a good proof would work: begin with some element in A, and show that the element exists in B. That implies that A is a subset of B. Then, show that some element in B exists in A; thus, B is a subset of A. If they are subsets of each other, then they are equal.

Choosing one specific example doesn't suffice; if it did, then we'd prove that the set of all primes equal the set of all evens (the number $2$ is in both set) which is obviously wrong. So we'll prove accordingly:

1. $A \subset B:$ Choose some $a \in A$. $a$ must be of the form $2m+1$, where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Fix $m=n+1$. Then, $a$ is of the form $2(n+1)+1=2n+3$. Thus, $a\in B$. We've shown that $a \in A \rightarrow a \in B$; therefore, $A \subset B$.
2. $B \subset A:$ Choose some $b \in B$. $b$ must be of the form $2n+3$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Fix $n=m-1$. Then, $b$ is of the form $2(m-1)+3=2m+1$. Thus, $b\in A$. We've shown that $b \in B \rightarrow b \in A$; therefore, $B \subset A$.

$A \subset B \land B \subset A \implies A=B.$